# Upgrading ag grid version from 27 to 28 but am not getting import for AgGridModule?

Tags: import, runtime-error, syntax-error, ag-grid-angular, angular15

After adding all the packages like community , enterprise, angular
I am not getting any import for AgGridModule?
Any specific reason?

How I will get import for AgGridModule
I am using angular 15 version and ag-grid 28.2.1 version